# 'function' object has no attribute 'display_formatter'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have this python program that I am trying to run on a shell from Jupyter notebook. The code works perfectly in the notebook, but when I export to the shell I keep getting this error

`'function' object has no attribute 'display_formatter'`

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
from scipy import spatial 
from IPython import get_ipython


def make_mask(b,image):
    mask=np.zeros((image.shape[0],image.shape[1],1),dtype=np.unint8)
    for xx,yy in enumarate(b):
        mask[yy:,xx]=255
    return mask


def display_mask(b,image,color=[0,0,255]):
    result=image.copy()
    overlay=np.full(image.shape,color,image.dtype)

    display(cv2.addWeighted(cv2.bitwise_and(overlay,overlay,mask=make_mask(b,image)),1,image,1,0,result))

def display_cv2_image(image):
    return cv2.imencode('.png', image)[1].tostring()


ip=get_ipython()
png_f = ip.display_formatter.formatters['image/png']
png_f.for_type_by_name('numpy', 'ndarray', display_cv2_image);
```

I have explicitly imported IPython but still no progress.

Comment: Did you mean: ‘ip=get_ipython()’?

Comment: Yes,Thank you for that correction

Comment: Is this question still valid, or did that correction solve your problem?

Comment: its still valid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it.
The work of I get_ipython is Get the global InteractiveShell instance and Return None if no InteractiveShell instance is registered Works fine in a notebook.

i found two ways on how to solve.
1.Importing get_ipython in an ordinary shell will not work untill you run via ipython it will create get_python as a global variable

```
$ ipython python/myscripy.py
```

2.Comment out all the get_ipython commands as you have a ready python shell instance running

I hope that will help someone also